# Could not find class india for puppetmaster

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I created a module named as bharath as below..

```
$ pwd
>> /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules

$ ls -lrth
>> total 8.0K  
>> drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K Apr 18 08:01 motd  
>> drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K Apr 18 13:09 bharath  

$ cd bharath/

$ ls -lrt
>> total 16
>> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 18 12:59 templates
>> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 18 13:10 files
>> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 18 13:15 manifests
>> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 18 13:16 tests h

$ cat manifests/init.pp files/india1 tests/init.pp

class india {

  file { '/root/india1':
    ensure => 'file',
    source => 'puppet:///modules/bharath/india1',
  }  
}

india is grat country --> files/india1 content    
include india --> tests/init.pp content
```

But still i am getting error as below..eventhough i added class india in stie.pp node classification directive as well.

```
$ cd tests
$ puppet apply --noop init.pp

>> Error: Could not find class india for uppetmaster.bharathkumarraju.com on node uppetmaster.bharathkumarraju.com
>> Error: Could not find class india for uppetmaster.bharathkumarraju.com on node puppetmaster.bharathkumarraju.com
```

Comment: It's very unclear what's going on. You pasted the output of `cat` with multiple file name arguments. You then apparently added annotations to the output. Don't do either of those things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `puppet apply` you need to set your `modulepath` on the command line.

```
$ puppet apply --modulepath /path/to/modules --noop init.pp
```

As @FelixFrank stated, you should reformat your question to make it more clear what you are asking, as well as better read the files you are `cat`'ing.

Hope this helps